# Creating custom editors for components with custom classes

Tags: unity

Let's say that I have the following Component

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public int health = 0;
    public int maxHealth = 100;

}
```

It is cool, but the editor could look better. So  I wrote this Custom Editor

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestPlayer))]
public class TestPlayerEditor : Editor {

    private SerializedProperty health;
    private SerializedProperty maxHealth;

    private void OnEnable() {
        health    = serializedObject.FindProperty("health");
        maxHealth = serializedObject.FindProperty("maxHealth");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        serializedObject.UpdateIfDirtyOrScript();

        EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(health, 0, maxHealth.intValue, "Health");

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(maxHealth, new GUIContent("Max Health"));
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Great. Now the Editor looks much better

[image]

But now turns out that because I am getting more properties of my Player with a similar pattern, I want to refactor it...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public FillingProperty hp;
    public FillingProperty stamina;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class FillingProperty {
    public int val;
    public int max;
}
```

How could I write now the Custom Editor script, so that the inspect shows me the same interface as before, but for every `FillableProperty` I wish to add?

Comment: I believe the answer is "not easily."  I fiddled with custom editor scripts once and it was a HUGE headache.  I *think* what you need is a script that is tagged, `[CustomEditor(typeof(FillingProperty))]` and is roughly identical to your current `TestPlayerEditor` editor script.  Then Unity will be able to parse your `TestPlayer` class natively and convert the FillingProperties to bars.

Comment: What do you mean with "rouhgly identical"? What would be different?

Comment: i think calling base.OnInspectorGUI() in OnInspectorGUI puts defaults elements in layout order.

Comment: Enrique: what I mean is, you'd be writing a class to display the same information in the same way, just that it would be tied to a data type rather than to the Monobehaviour script.  You might have to experiment a little, it's been a while since I fiddled with editor scripts.